# Magento 2 - Get product attributes selected value via MySQL

Tags: database, magento2.4

I am trying to get a products selected attribute value via MySQL.

Basically, what I need is the SQL equivalent of this:

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)
```

Does any one know how I can return the same result but by using a MySQL query?

(I have tried adding ->getSelect() to the end but it doesn't work.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
select
   a.frontend_label as attribute,
   ao.*
from
   catalog_product_entity p

   left join catalog_product_entity_int av on
      p.entity_id = av.entity_id

   left join eav_attribute a on
      av.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
   left join eav_attribute_option_value ao on
      av.value = ao.option_id 
where
   p.entity_id = 5
   AND
   a.frontend_label = 'Accessory Type'
;
```

Found this here: https://newbedev.com/how-are-product-attributes-and-attribute-options-stored-in-magento-database

(Thanks Newbedev!)

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works..!

The attributes are stored in `eav_attribute`. There you get the `attribute_id`.

```
SELECT cpe.entity_id ,cpe.sku, cpei.value FROM catalog_product_entity_int as cpei LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe ON cpei.row_id = cpe.row_id WHERE cpei.attribute_id = {'your_attribute_id'};
```

Note that depending on the type of attribute, there are various tables like catalog_product_entity_int.

Thanks !!!